# Retrieve all rows from DataTable in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, datatable

I have created a temporary `datatable` to store temporary data before send it to database. But after creating that now i want to fetch all the rows from this temporary `datatable` and save them to data base. For this i loop my `datatable` using foreach loop

```
   foreach(DataRow r in dt.Rows)
        {
            string Fname = dt.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();
            string cType = dt.Rows[0]["ContentType"].ToString();
            byte[] ePic = (byte[])dt.Rows[0]["pic"];
            BAL.saveEventPictures(Convert.ToInt32(lblEventID.Text), Fname, cType, ePic);
        }
```

The problem is that it only fetch the data of first row again and again for the whole loop count. Like if I have 4 `datarows` with different information, then this will store the data of 1st row in the database for 4 times. What mistake am i doing?

Comment: That's because you are specifically indexing the first row only.

Comment: @IrishChieftain then what i suppose to do and how?

Comment: @IrishChieftain I GOT IT. Thanks :)

Comment: instead of `dt.Rows[0]` use `r`, eg: `string Fname = r["Name"].ToString();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dt.Rows[0]` means you are always accessing **the first row** of your `DataTable`.You need to use a `for` loop instead of a `foreach` and use `i` to access each index of your table:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    string Fname = dt.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString();
    string cType = dt.Rows[i]["ContentType"].ToString();
    byte[] ePic = (byte[])dt.Rows[i]["pic"];
    BAL.saveEventPictures(Convert.ToInt32(lblEventID.Text), Fname, cType, ePic);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for` loop to fetch all value regarding their columns in datatable to assign value in their variables so you can use this way. Because if you use hard coded index of datatable rows then it should fetch only single data every time.

Here `i` is index of rows and column name to get value from rows. So use dynamically based indexing use for get all records.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    string Fname = dt.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString();
    string cType = dt.Rows[i]["ContentType"].ToString();
    byte[] ePic = (byte[])dt.Rows[i]["pic"];
    BAL.saveEventPictures(Convert.ToInt32(lblEventID.Text), Fname, cType, ePic);
}
```